How to use Rust crates from git in Yocto Scarthgap?
I have a Rust application with the following in the Cargo.toml file:
[dependencies]
sqlx = { version = "0.7.2", features = ["sqlite"] }

[patch.crates-io]
sqlx = { git = 'https://github.com/b2vn/sqlx.git', branch = "unbundle-sqlite-v0.7.2" }

My Yocto receipe contains:
inherit cargo
..
SRC_URI += "git://github.com/b2vn/sqlx.git;protocol=https;nobranch=1;name=sqlx;destsuffix=cargo_home/git/db/sqlx-bb8453b7fdc019eb "\
..
SRCREV_FORMAT .= "_sqlx"
SRCREV_sqlx = "2011c51876fa084de32f3956d637f38effb369e5"

While this seems to work (I got this from a project I took over) I don't understand why the naming of the folder used by Yocto - "sqlx-bb8453b7fdc019eb" from the above recipe works while a different hash doesn't.
I have so many questions ..

Why is the hash important?
How is it calculated? I'm unable to find any information about how this is supposed to work, so any hints would be welcome. :)


You might want to take a look at cargo-bitbake, specifically the patched version for scarthgap: cargo install --git https://github.com/jaskij/cargo-bitbake.git. Although I'm not entirely sure if that actually is relevant for your problem.

Thanks. :) I think that Yocto is using this hash https://users.rust-lang.org/t/origin-of-hash-in-folder-name-for-cargo-git-dependencies/110930. As usual I found a reference to it after posting here. :)
I can see the same hash being generated when I build the same project using cargo. I guess that I should ask and then update the Yocto documentation.
